# Reader return the value 63?

Tags: java, file, binary, writer, reader

I tried to write random numbers with the Writer in a binary file and read it out with the Reader. So far, so good. But sometimes the Reader displays me the value 63 as opposed to the right number. Why does the programm display me the value 63?

For example:
38 193 74 115 84 203 123 6 190 76 **151** 11 **148** 122 240 241 162 232 224 92 164 43 247 81 31 226 163 117 116 202 90 66 16 14 63 174 78 182 92 195 77 196 112 194 **153** 204
======== Wrote ========
38 193 74 115 84 203 123 6 190 76 **63** 11 **63** 122 240 241 162 232 224 92 164 43 247 81 31 226 163 117 116 202 90 66 16 14 63 174 78 182 92 195 77 196 112 194 **63** 204

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numb;
    File file = new File("randNumbers.txt");
    Writer fw = null;

    try
    {
        fw = new FileWriter(file);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            numb = rand.nextInt(256);
            System.out.print(numb + " ");
            fw.write(numb);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("======== Wrote ========");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(fw != null)
        {
            try
            {
                fw.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // read random numbers from file
    Reader fr = null;

    try
    {
        fr = new FileReader(file);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(fr.read() + " ");
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(fr != null)
        {
            try
            {
                fr.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating random numbers as if they were all valid characters in the default charset of your system. That's not the case.

63 is the numeric value of the question mark, which is used to replace a value that doesn't represent any valid character in the charset.

It seems you don't actually want to write characters in a text file, but random bytes in a binary file. You should thus use a FileOutputStream to write, and a FileInputStream to read.